# New to php programming, simple syntax error which I can't seem to resolve

Tags: php

I'm having a go at PHP programming and bumped into some troubles with my syntax. I don't seem to understand PHP well enough to resolve this syntax error, though it should be pretty obvious to a trained eye. I'm hoping I can find the solution to the error here.

I have a login page written in HTML/PHP called login.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
 <body>
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION["user"])) {
    echo "<p>Welcome back, " . $_SESSION["user"] . "!<br>";
    echo '<a href="process.php?action=logout">Logout</a></p>';
}
else {
?>
  <form action="process.php?action=login" method="post">
   <p>The username is: admin</p>
   <input type="text" name="user" size="20">
   <p>The password is: test</p>
   <input type="password" name="pass" size="20">
   <input type="submit" value="Login">
  </form>
<?php
}
?>
 </body>
</html>
```

which routes to a process.php, where the error happens at line 8 at the ;

```
<?php
session_start();

switch($_GET["action"]) {
    case "login":
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            $user = (isset($_POST["user"]) && 
              ctype_alnum($_POST["user"]) ? $_POST["user"] : null;
            $pass = (isset($_POST["pass"])) ? $_POST["pass"] : null;
            $salt = '$2a$07$my.s3cr3t.SalTY.str1nG$';

            if (isset($user, $pass) && (crypt($user . $pass, $salt) ==
                crypt("admintest", $salt))) {
                $_SESSION["user"] = $_POST["user"];
            }
        }
        break;

    case "logout":
        $_SESSION = array();
        session_destroy();
        break;
}

header("Location: login.php");
?>
```

The error message I receive from the webserver is the following, and happens whenever I press the "login" button.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xsrf/process.php on line 8
```

Any help with resolving this syntax error would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Double check your parentheses on the line with `$user = `.

Comment: `(isset($_POST["user"])` where are you closing this?

Comment: Use a syntax-highlighting editor, and/or a syntax checker / linter. These are problems for tools, not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to close a parenthesis.

Try to change :

```
$user = (isset($_POST["user"]) && ctype_alnum($_POST["user"]) ? $_POST["user"] : null;
```

By :

```
$user = (isset($_POST["user"]) && ctype_alnum($_POST["user"])) ? $_POST["user"] : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

`$user = (isset($_POST["user"]) && 
              ctype_alnum($_POST["user"]) ? $_POST["user"] : null;`

I guess you didn't close the first isset parenthesis !

Comment: Can you format your answer?

Comment: done, sorry i'm not used to post here. ^^

Comment: You will learn it by the time :)